# Subject in the middle of sentence. What grammar is it?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

What kind of grammar is used in this sentence?

> In school, while actively interacting with other students, **children** actually are practicing how to communicate with others.

Particularly my question is about `children` that is used in the middle of the sentence as a subject. If I'm going to say something like that, I'd say:

> In school, **children** are actively interacting with other students while practicing how to communicate with others.

Comment: [*In English grammar, **fronting** refers to any construction in which a word group that customarily follows the verb is placed at the beginning of a sentence.*](https://www.thoughtco.com/fronting-in-grammar-1690875#:~:text=In%20English%20grammar%2C%20fronting%20refers,enhance%20cohesion%20and%20provide%20emphasis.) The default sequence in English is Subject+Verb+Object, with any adverbial element normally coming immediately before or after the verb. Your first example has **2** "fronted" adverbial elements, either or both of which could have been moved closer to the verb phrase they modify.

Answer (score 5):

What you have here is an *introductory clause*. Parenthetical phrases can often be placed differently in a sentence, as free modifiers.

Your main clause is essentially this:

> Children are practising how to communicate with others.

But your example is specifically about children (i) in school, and (ii) when they interact with other children, and this information is included to further define both the subject and the conditions under which the statement is true.

You could keep the subject first and add this information in other ways:

> Children *in school* are practising how to communicate with others *while actively interacting with other students*.

Different placing of defining details is very common and often has no effect on the meaning:

> -We are going to the zoo *today*.
> -*Today*, we are going to the zoo.

However, in your specific example, the way it is rendered seems best. 'While' can mean both "during", and "at the same time as". Rendered as it is, it comes across that the learning is a result of the interaction, whereas the alternate way I rendered it sounds more like two things happening at the same time.